# PHP OAuth authentication working with params in URL but not in header

Tags: php, oauth

I am developing an API using OAuth authentication. The following works well:

```
require 'OAuth.php';

$key = 'apiuser@domain.com';
$secret = '9HasdFqM2ygI5Be4';
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($key, $secret);

$api_endpoint ='https://mysite.com/api/users/useremail@userdomain.com';

$parameters = array();
$req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, null, 'GET', $api_endpoint, $parameters);
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$req->sign_request($sig_method, $consumer, null);
$ch = curl_init($req->to_url());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The value of $req->to_url() in the above is something like the following. It even works when copied straight into a web browser:

https://mysite.com/api/users/useremail@userdomain.com?oauth_consumer_key=apiuser%40domain.com&oauth_nonce=74a43737c8638b7531c948ca98e02500&oauth_signature=550R8aPmRfsZo6d%2BArEK0R2w9x0%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1404900356&oauth_version=1.0

I need to be able to allow requests via http header as well. Here is my code, however I cannot get it to authenticate:

```
require 'OAuth.php';

$key = 'apiuser@domain.com';
$secret = '9HasdFqM2ygI5Be4';
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($key, $secret);

$api_endpoint ='https://mysite.com/api/users/useremail@userdomain.com';

$parameters = array();
$req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, null, 'GET', $api_endpoint, $parameters);
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$req->sign_request($sig_method, $consumer, null);
$url = sprintf("%s?%s", $api_endpoint, OAuthUtil::build_http_query($parameters));
$ch = curl_init();  
$headers = array($req->to_header());

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

For reference here is the code at the other side performing the authentication:

```
$oauth_consumer_key = false;
$oauth_signature = false;

// Check for parameters in HTTP request header
$request_headers = getallheaders();
if (isset($request_headers['Authorization'])) {
    $header_parameters = OAuthUtil::split_header($request_headers['Authorization']);
    if (isset($header_parameters['oauth_consumer_key'])) {
        $oauth_consumer_key = $header_parameters['oauth_consumer_key'];
    }
    if (isset($header_parameters['oauth_signature'])) {
        $oauth_signature = urlencode($header_parameters['oauth_signature']);
    }
}

// If not found, check for parameters in $_GET
if (!$oauth_consumer_key) {
    if (isset($_GET['oauth_consumer_key'])) {
        $oauth_consumer_key = $_GET['oauth_consumer_key'];
    }
}
if (!$oauth_signature) {
    if (isset($_GET['oauth_signature'])) {
        $oauth_signature = $_GET['oauth_signature'];
    }
}

// If parameters not found, output error
if (!$oauth_consumer_key or !$oauth_signature) {
    sendResponseAndExitIf(true, 400);
}

// some code here to retrieve $consumer_secret from database based on $oauth_consumer_key

// build uri
$uri = 'http';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
        $uri .= 's';
    }
}
$uri .= '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($oauth_consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$req = new OAuthRequest('GET', $uri);

//token is null because we're doing 2-leg
$authenticated = $sig_method->check_signature($req, $consumer, null, $oauth_signature);
```

As stated $authenticated returns true for the first method (params in URL) but false for the second method (params in http header). I have output to screen the values of uri, consumer key, consumer secret etc. to make sure they are the same on both client and server sides. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to supply the header parameters when creating the OAuthRequest before authenticating, so

```
$req = new OAuthRequest($method, $uri, $parameters);
```

instead of just

```
$req = new OAuthRequest($method, $uri);
```

Found this after dumping every piece of data I could think on both client and server side and comparing each one.